# How to make a link open in the default browser in C#?

Tags: c#, linklabel

I want to make a button that puts users in their default browser in Visual Studio '19
I'm making a C# windows form application, and I have a button to a discord server for users
Does anyone have an answer?
Currently I use

```
        private void linkLabel2_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {

        Call: OpenUrl("discord.gg/FMxXdmnCxg");
        }

        private static void OpenUrl(string url)
        {
            Process pro = new Process();
            pro.StartInfo.FileName = "msedge.exe";
            pro.StartInfo.Arguments = url;
            pro.Start();
        }
```

Should I keep with this or should I change it?

Comment: no, I want to put a default browser script or at least open in edge, not explorer

Comment: @Shiba01 The process.start(url) does start the default browser, not Explorer (unless the user has Internet Explorer as their default browser).

Comment: @B.O.B. Will this work?
`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("discord.gg/FMxXdmnCxg`

Comment: Include the protocol (https://)

Comment: @Martheen So,
I should use
`
`private void ButtonDiscord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://discord.gg/FMxXdmnCxg");
}
`

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
static void OpenUrl(string url)
{
    ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    processInfo.FileName = url;
    processInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    Process.Start(processInfo);
}
```

Comment: Do I use this but replace the "url" with the actual URL?

Comment: You should call the method `OpenUrl("https://example.com/")`